# Keeping XHR requests going when iOS put in the background

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm writing an app that uses https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova to authenticate with Azure AD. It opens an embedded browser within the app that shows our Azure AD page and the user enters their credentials. Because we require multi factor authentication the system then sends them a push notification which if tapped* opens the Microsoft Authenticator app.

Using Safari's debug tools I can see that before switching over to Authenticator it is making repeated to requests https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/EndAuth, each time getting a response including "The authentication has not been completed yet, please try again." However once the Authenticator app is running (and my app is in the background) the requests pause and after approval is done I return to my app the last request that was made turns red (in the Safari inspector).

[image: EndAuth failed]

I believe I need to mark my app as being able to run in the background, but since the page that loses the connection is from AzureAD perhaps there is a setting or fix there that can restart the auth requests when the app returns to the front.

*If the user pulls down on the notification they are offered two buttons "approve" and "deny". My app is obscured by the notification but no other app has really taken focus. In this case when Approve is pressed the final request to ....EndAuth is successful, the app knows it is authenticated and everything proceeds.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? We are seeing similar problems when using SMS based MFA where a user must switch applications to respond.

Comment: @John No luck here

Comment: I know it's been a while since this was asked but I'm having the same issue with the Authenticator App, did you find any solution?